# ovpn config file for Tunnelblick

Tags: openvpn

I am currently doing configuration Tunnelblick for MacOs for which I do not have configuration file, I have IP address to connect to.I am creating configuration file for the same & currently a bit stuck with following 3 settings for configuration file. Can anyone help me with the steps/reference to create these .crt and .key for MacOs.
-I tried to generate new certificates with Keychain access manager but that wasn't of any help to me :(

- Tried  command : `sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out myCA.key 2048 >generated myCA.key`
- Tried  command `sudo openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.pem >generated myCA.pem`

I am not able to create following files for the ovpn
-CA Cert    CA certification file.  ca.crt
-Cert   Client certification file.  client.crt
-Key    key client.key  client.key

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently doing configuration Tunnelblick for MacOs for which I do not have configuration file, I have IP address to connect to.

> I am not able to create following files for the ovpn -CA Cert CA certification file. ca.crt -Cert Client certification file. client.crt -Key key client.key client.key

So you are configuring a connection to an external VPN server.

The answer is that you *can't* generate those certificates. You have to get them from the entity that runs the VPN server. The CA certificate has to be the one configured at the remote end, and your certificate has to be issued by that CA.

If you wish to generate the key material for your certificate locally, you may send them a [Certificate Signing Request](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-generate/csr-generation-guide-for-nginx-openssl/), but the downsides to letting them generate this for you is rather low in this scenario; they *will* have access to your traffic authenticated by the certificate anyhow.